# Configure Gitlab to run tests on my own server

Tags: github, github-actions

I come from GitLab land where I am used to configure my CI / CD with the `.gitlab-ci.yml`. Now I am facing GitHub and want to trigger pull_request actions that should run pre-merge tests either on GitHub itself or on my own server.

I am confused from the github action setup and to figure the right yml config that would do what I want. How do I make merge conditional on workflow (test) success?

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice [documentation about the github actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions) and there exists an [auto-merge option](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-02-04-pull-request-auto-merge-is-now-generally-available/).

In general you can say that all actions are in the folder `.github/workflows`. You can also create them via the `Actions` tab. For your workflow you have to use the event [`pull_request`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request) that is triggered for pull requests.

You can also [host your own Github runners](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners) if you want to host them yourself.